# JavaScript Variable Input From Page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for how to get input from a webpage into a JavaScript variable?

**[EDIT]**

Sorry I wasn't clear. I needed to get a user to input some text that I could capture into a variable. I then need to split this variable up, do a search, like Google on each element, then display the results on the screen.

As I understand it I can use jQuery's get method to look up the information, then get each response out and put it on the screen. Thanks for the pointers to jQuery I can now proceed further

Comment: That's really not a question. Expand it a bit more to explain what you want and preferably show some code you have tried that doesn't work.

Comment: read the [faq]. You need to do a little legwork before expecting people to go out of their way to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. One would be to have an input field of type text, then attach an event listener to the input field which responds to the enter key?

```
<input type="text" id="commandLine"/>
```

then in js

```
$("#commandLine").bind('keydown' function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        var command = $("#commandLine").val();
        //Do stuff with the command
    }
});
```

Or if you want to interrupt flow until you get a response, you could use `prompt` eg.

```
var command = prompt("What is your command?","");
alert(command );
```

As pointed out my code above requires jQuery - this is a library which makes using javascript much easier when coding for multiple browsers.  It's worth taking a look at it at http://jquery.com it's very easy to make use of by simply adding in a script tag pointing at the jQuery library eg.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" />`

Comment: How can I then split up the variable?

Comment: Wouldn't the "change" event be more effective than binding to keydown? Also the OP didn't specify a framework so giving them the answer in jQuery, when they don't know how to do in javascript, and not telling them it requires jQuery is misleading.

Comment: @JefftyJeff Split up based on what? Use the .split() method? You need to be mich more specific.

Comment: Split by what?  If the variable is a text input it could be anything, you can perform validation on it, then split using the .split("tokenizer") method? eg var.split(",") would give you an array of strings where each one was separated by a "," in the original string.

Comment: I think the prompt method is what I need. I want the user to be interrupted, enter a list of things, then I want to go and look up those things and put the results on the page. Can I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = document.getElementById("formElementId").value;
```

Although I'd recommend jQuery or similar.